# Varian Analysis Non satiation question

Tags: macroeconomics, microeconomics, utility, consumer-theory, preferences

Consider preferences defined over the nonnegative orthant by (xl,x2)> (yl,y2) if X1 + X2 < y1+ y2. Do these preferences exhibit local nonsatiation? If these are the only two consumption goods and the consumer faces positive prices, will the consumer spend all of his income? Explain.